# How to compare two objects by their fields?

Tags: java, serialization, equals

I have pretty large number of classes which are `Serializable`/`Externalizable` and unfortunately it happens quite often that I forget to serailize/desirialize a new field when adding it to a class or mispell `readObject` instead of `readDouble`. So I decided to write some sort of unit test which is ignored and won't run by `maven-surefire-plugin`. It's only for my own needs. It looks like this:

```
@Test(enabled = false)
public void testEquality(Object o){
    String oPart = o.toString();
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/myusr/testser/" + oPart);
         ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
        ous.writeObject(o);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Object oo = null;
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/home/myusr/testser/" + oPart);
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
        Object oo =  ois.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    // Need to compare all non-transient fields of o and oo
}
```

But the question is how to compare all fields which are not `transient` with the same name. I would not want to override `equals` method just for testing purpose.

Is there a way to deal with it? Maybe there are some `commons`/`guava` libraries which can cope with that.

Comment: Have you seen [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to do it starting with `YourClaas.class.getDeclaredFields()`. Then you have to filter the returned fields, retrieve the values from the objects and do the comparison.